# how to convert ISO date comming from web api to date formatted as dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

```
<script 
$(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://localhost:44390/api/Contract_Alg",
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#contract").DataTable({
                        data: data,
                        columns: [
                            { 'data': 'ContractID' },
                            { 'data': 'Code_ID' },
                            {
                                'data': 'ContractStartDate'
                            },
                            { 'data': 'ContractEndtDate' },
                            { 'data': 'Contract_Verfication' },
                            { 'data': 'First_Contract' },
                            { 'data': 'ALgerian_Info' }
                        ],
                      

                    });
                }
            })
        });
```

Hello,
i have datatable code for rendering data from web api asp.net
everything is ok until i get date formatted like that '2019-12-16T00:00:00'
iso date, please help me to convert it to dd-mm-yyyy
here is my code:

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `moment.js` library for time related operations

install moment.js in your application or add the script tag for it

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

then use it to convert ISO date to any [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) you like

```js
moment( yourIsoDateString ).format('DDD-M-YYYY');
```

and since you are using data table you need to process the `data` variable before its passed to datatable.

assuming you data to be

```js
const formattedData = data.map( item => ({ 

    ...item,
    ContractStartDate: moment( item.ContractStartDate ).format('DDD-M-YYYY')

 })
```

then pass the `formattedData` to the datatable

applying these changes to your code would result in

```js
success: function (data) {

               const formattedData = data.map( item => ({ 

                ...item,
                 ContractStartDate: moment( item.ContractStartDate ).format('DDD-M-YYYY'),
                 ContractEndtDate: moment( item.ContractEndtDate ).format('DDD-M-YYYY'),

                 });


                    $("#contract").DataTable({
                        data: formattedData,
                        columns: [
                            { 'data': 'ContractID' },
                            { 'data': 'Code_ID' },
                            {
                                'data': 'ContractStartDate'
                            },
                            { 'data': 'ContractEndtDate' },
                            { 'data': 'Contract_Verfication' },
                            { 'data': 'First_Contract' },
                            { 'data': 'ALgerian_Info' }
                        ],
                      

                    });
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
Could you please show me how to fix these part of code :
                          {
                                'data': 'ContractStartDate',
                                'render': function () {
                         // function covert iso date to dd-mm-yyyy
                                   
                                }
                            },
I want to render function convert

Comment: I tried explain the point in a new update to the answer, hope it will help you